# Need to buy a MacBook Pro with a French Canadian keyboard but don't live in Canada

Tags: keyboard, internationalization, apple-store

I live in Japan and I need to buy a new MacBook Pro with a French Canadian keyboard (physical, not just changing the keyboard layout in the OS).

The option of a French Canadian keyboard is only available on the Canadian Apple website, it is not available on the Japan Apple website neither any other Apple websites, and Apple Canada doesn't deliver abroad.

Any hint on a solution?

Answer (score 12):

I have had good luck calling the pre-sales support number from the online store where I live (in your case call the Japanese support number from the online web store localized for Japan).

They can add the part you require even though it’s “off the menu” or explain why and how to get your item. Often I’ll place in my cart the proper external keyboard so they can confirm the exact layout desired and then I remove that before ordering.

I prefer this strongly over paying a company to order and then reship it from the “easy” country as that costs more in money and time and risk they don’t order exactly what you need or you have to hassle with using their shipping address for your account in another country.

Comment: Interesting!  Could you give a example of what language keyboard laptop not offered in your country you were able to obtain that way?  Until now the only solution (other than reshipment) I had heard was to buy from a non-Apple source.

Comment: We got a Japanese one and another I can’t recall in the US @TomGewecke - it took a long while the second attempt. Perhaps someone did what they shouldn’t and pulled strings against policy?

Comment: I think Japanese has always been available in the US online store.  Hebrew, Greek, and Swedish are ones I have seen people asking for without success.  I made a list at    http://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2021/11/macos-hardware-keyboard-availability.html

Comment: How have I not seen your blog @TomGewecke ?!! Thanks for that list. I recall struggling to help someone get a Swedish Mac back a long time ago in retail store land here.